# Simplify an expression with the integral of a squared summation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(f(x)-\left[\frac{c_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx} + d_n\sin{nx}\right]\right)^2dx$$

First I apply the binomial theorem to get:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx - 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\left(\frac{c_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx} + d_n\sin{nx}\right)dx+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{c_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx} + d_n\sin{nx}\right)^2dx$$

Then apply it again to the last term:

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx - 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\left(\frac{c_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx} + d_n\sin{nx}\right)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{c_0^2}4+c_0+\left[\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx} + d_n\sin{nx}\right]^2\right)dx$$

At this point I get stuck with the last integral. In the solutions manual I see the last term is expanded as

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{c_0^2}4+\sum_{n=1}^N c_n^2\cos^2{nx} + d_n^2\sin^2{nx}\right)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum_{n,m=1}^N c_nd_m\cos{nx}\sin{mx}\right)dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{c_0}2\sum_{n=1}^N c_n\cos{nx}+d_n\sin{nx}\right)dx$$

How exactly did they do it? Where did they lose $c_0$ from the last integral? Am I missing some theorem for squares of summations?

Comment: Try with $N=2$ or $N=3$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the formula should be $\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)\right]^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1, j=i+1}^{n-1}(a_i+b_i)(a_j+b_j)$. Seems very tedious to applying it here, but feels like all the $\cos{mx}\cos{nx}$, $\cos{mx}\sin{nx}$ and $\sin{mx}\sin{nx}$ would collapse to 0 in the end.